# How to change the time in .php

Tags: php, time, echo

I want to convert the time when i echo from database to .php page.
When i upload a csv to database the table row with duration looks like this:

TABLE ROW:

```
|Duration|          

500     >   5:00
234     >   2:34
1100    >   11:00
520     >   5:20
1300    >   13:00
10000   >   1:00:00
```

So what i want is to show it like this > 5:00.

If i change the TABLE ROW Duration in to TIME than i get this 00:05:00.

So what do i need to change it like above explained ?
Hopefully I explained it well

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
foreach (array(500, 234, 1100, 520, 1300, 10000) as $number) {
    echo $number, "\t";
    $number = str_pad($number, 6, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
    echo ltrim($number{0}.$number{1}.':'.$number{2}.$number{3}.':'.$number{4}.$number{5}, ":0"), "\n";
}
```

http://codepad.org/FrjWtgqx

Comment: Woow ! Thank`s, and if i dont know if i already have some rows like 5:00 and thousend rows of numbers ? what should i need to type it one for one ? Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Function [`wordwrap()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) could be useful:

```php
foreach (['500', '234', '1100', '520', '1300', '10000'] as $number) {
    $time = strrev($number);
    $time = wordwrap($time, 2, ':', true);
    $time = strrev($time);
    echo "$number was transformed to $time\n";
}
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/136892)</kbd>